# PHP Converting a date to a timestamp

Tags: php, datetime

How do I convert "9/7/2009" into a timestamp, such as one from `time()`? Do I use `strtotime()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) for that

```
$time = strtotime('9/7/2009');
echo $time; // 1252278000
```

This will assume a format of mm/dd/yyyy so don't try it with UK-style dd/mm/yyyy dates.

To go the other way, use [`date()`](http://php.net/date)

```
$date = date('n/j/Y', $time);
echo $date; // 9/7/2009
```

Answer (score 2):

strtotime() is correct.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

You can test to be sure by putting the returned timestamp back in the date() function.

```
<?php echo date("m-d-Y",strtotime("9/7/2009")); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strptime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) if you want to be more precise about the format to parse, and remember that when people in the rest of the world see "9/7/2009" they read 9th July 2009, not 7th September 2009.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's MM/DD/YY as the standard format - am I incorrect?

Comment: Yeah, `MM/DD/YY` is the format `strtotime()` assumes by default for months - but I was talking about when people read a date, not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

A newer way to do this as of PHP 5.3 is to use the [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) with the [`getTimestamp()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) method:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('9/7/2009');
echo $datetime->getTimestamp();
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/bEBKy3)